# why std::set in function from <algorithm> changes non-const object to const?

Tags: algorithm, c++11, set

I have 10000 non-const objects in std::vector. I want to put them in the std::set.

```
set<Object,bool(*)(Object, Object)> s([](Object a, Object b){
                                     return a.getId() < b.getId()});
```

I want to change some variables in this objects.

```
for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [=](Object& a){
    a.setId(new_id);
  });
```

Why when I'm using set in functions from , it gives me the error that object "would lose const qualifier". But with vector everything is normal. I have a couple of thoughts:
1) in for_each it's automatically used const_iterator.
2) the set just cast non-const to const, but i think it's wrong because i can without problem gets with iterator an object and change it.

Can someone explain me, what happens here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can't modify elements in a `std::set`. The set has no way of knowing what you have changed and would invalidate it. If you could, it would allow the possibility that it would break the strict-weak ordering invariant, resulting in undefined behavior.

If you want to modify an element, then you should erase the element, and insert a new one. I think the *force constantness* is to prevent the attempt to modify the elements.